# Identify the element is hyper link on directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive as shown below.Can you tell me how to filter the hyper link elements from it ? In other words, how to identify the element is hyper link ? Thanks in advance.

```
app.directive('toggler', function ($document) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.open = false;

      element.on('click', function (e) {
        scope.$apply(function () { 
          scope.open = true;      //onclick open tooltip and call digest so the ng-if see the change
        });
        e.stopPropagation(); //stop event from bubbling up to document object
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `tagName` property. [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/X9m2ULFCwOZvBvIG5USa)

```
if (element[0].tagName === 'A') {}
```